# How Can I Achieve this custom card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

How Can I Achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 2):

here is the code, **the idea is to use images that doesn't have a background**, the code uses svg image to achieve that and svg package to open images with that extension.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Card demo'),),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MyCard(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
    );
  }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 400,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 60,),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20),topRight: Radius.circular(20),),
                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20), bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),)
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('\$ 172',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            Spacer(),
                            Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.red,),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text('Your Description Here',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Container(
             width: 200,
              height: 300,
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/core/assets/images/4.svg',fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

hope it helps you.